# Ubuntu can't mount my formatted SDcard

Tags: mount, automount, sd-card

I tested it before formatting, working fine, then I used "Disks" (pre-installed) to format it.
After that, both my file managers (Nautilus and Nemo) can't find our mount it. And also, "Disks" still recognize it and work with it.

What can be the problem?

Comment: how did you format it? add more information

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably didn't format the card, you probably just somehow deleted your previous partitions. In order to make the sd card mountable again do this:

Create a partition in the "Unallocated Space" for all of your sd card on disks. Name it whatever you want. Choose what it will be( I recommend FAT).

Answer (score 0):

[jack0da's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/855760/527764) may work but another issue that also comes up a lot is that the SD card isn't correctly placed in the port. Try shimmying it around or using an adapter if jack0da's answer doesn't work.